# The condition that a ring is a principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

If $R$ is a nonzero commutative ring with identity and every submodule of every free $R$-module is free, then $R$ is a principal ideal domain.

What I don't know is how to show that every ideal is free. Once an ideal is free, for nonzero $u,v\in I$, $uv-vu=0$ shows that the ideal has only one basis. that is, the ideal is principal. Any help?

Comment: Need to show that no two elements $u$, $v$ of $I$ are linearly independent. If one of them is zero, clear. If none, you just wrote some equality above. Btw,  $R$ PID $\iff$ submodules of free modules are also  free.

Comment: @orangeskid but how to show that under the condition "submodules of free modules are also free", ideal is free?

Comment: Oh, an ideal is a submodule of $R$, which is free, with basis the element $1$.

Comment: @orangeskid thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $R$ as $R$-module, then this is free, with basis $\lbrace 1 \rbrace $.

Suppose $I \subseteq R $ is an ideal, $I \neq 0 $; then $I$ is a submodule, whence it is free.  If $u, v \in I $ they are linearly dependent over $R$, because $vu -uv = 0 $.

This implies that if $B= \lbrace u_1, u_2, \ldots \rbrace $ is a basis for $I$ as $R$-module, then $|B| = 1 $, so $I = < w > $ and I is a  principal ideal.

For the domain part, if $a \in R $ , $a \neq 0 $, suppose $ba = 0 $ with $b \neq 0 $. Then consider $I = <a> $. By the previous part $I$ has a basis $\lbrace w \rbrace $. We have $w = k a $ for $ k \in R $. Then $$ bw = bka = k (ba) = 0$$ But $w $ is linearly independent and $b \neq 0 $. This is a contradiction and so $ba \neq 0 $.

Comment: @김김김: I've added the domain part