# Proving wrong that $R$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

So I know that the following argument I will give is not correct, but I can not understand why. Any help ? I am working with commutative rings.

Let $R$ be a ring such that any submodule of a free $R$-module is free. We prove that $R$ is a field by proving that the only ideals of $R$ are the trivial ones.

Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $R$. Since $R$ is a free module over itself, by assumption, the ideal is then a free $R$-submodule. However, for any elements $a,b\in I$ we have that $ab +(-b)a=0$. Therefore the cardinality of any basis of $I$ should be equal to 1. But a free $R$-module with one element in the basis is isomorphic to $R$. Thus $I=R$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: The correct conclusion is that $R$ is a PID (principal ideal domain).

Comment: Try your argument when $R$ is the polynomial ring $k[x]$ over a field $k$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The condition that a ring is a principal ideal domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960336/the-condition-that-a-ring-is-a-principal-ideal-domain)

Comment: In a P.I.D. $R$, any ideal is isomorphic to $R$, but not equal in general *Counter example*: in $\mathbf Z$, the ideal $n\mathbf Z$ maps isomorphically onto $\mathbf Z$ by the mapping $xn\mapsto x$, but it is equal to $\mathbf Z$  only if $n$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z$ (i.e. $\pm 1$).

Comment: Exactly. Just being *isomorphic* to $R$ does **not** mean that the ideal **equals** $R$.

Comment: I knew that the correct answer is "$R$ is a PID" but I did not see the problem with mine. Now I see, thanks to Andrew and Bernard !

Answer (score 3):

The following part is wrong:

> But a free $R$-module with one element in the basis is isomorphic to $R$. **Thus** $I=R$, which concludes the proof.

A ring can be isomorphic to an ideal without being equal.

To understand why your proof is wrong, consider the case $R=\mathbb Z$ and $I=2 \mathbb Z$.
Everything woorks well untill you show that $R$ and $I$ are isomorphic (they are as $R$-modules). But this does not imply that they are equal.

Also $R=\mathbb Z$ satisfies the given condition, but it is **not a field**. The result you are trying to prove is not correct. Try proving instead that every ideal in $R$ is principal.

**Note** You can also show that $R$ is an integral domain. Indeed, if $R$ has a $0$ divisor $a$, then $\langle a \rangle$ is a submodule of the free module $R$ which is not free.